# Goldstein test in nonlinear programming

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm reading about nonlinear programming and the Goldstein test. Here is the definition from my book:

> A line search accuracy test that is frequently used is the Goldstein
>   test. A value of $\alpha \geq0$ is considered not too small in the
>   Goldstein test if
>
> $$\phi(\alpha) > \phi(0) + (1-\epsilon)\phi'(0)\alpha,\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
>
> where $\phi(\alpha) = f(\textbf{x}+\alpha\textbf{d}),$ for some point
>   $\textbf{x}\in E^n$ and feasible direction $\textbf{d}\in E^n$. In
>   terms of the original notation, the Goldstein criterion for an
>   acceptable value of $\alpha$, with corresponding $\textbf{x}_{k+1} =
>  \textbf{x}_k+\alpha\textbf{d}_k$, is
>
> $$\epsilon \leq
>  \frac{f(\textbf{x}_{k+1})-f(\textbf{x}_k)}{\alpha\nabla f(\textbf{x}_k
>  )\textbf{d}_k}\leq 1-\epsilon.\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

[image]

My question is: Are $(1)$ and $(2)$ supposed to be the same expression, i.e. equivalent?

Because from $(1)$ I get:

$$\phi(\alpha) > \phi(0) + (1-\epsilon)\phi'(0)\alpha$$

$$<=> f(\textbf{x}_{k+1}) > f(\textbf{x}_k) + (1-\epsilon)\nabla f(\textbf{x}_k)\textbf{d}_k \alpha$$

$$<=> \frac{f(\textbf{x}_{k+1})-f(\textbf{x}_k)}{\nabla f(\textbf{x}_k)\textbf{d}_k \alpha} >1-\epsilon.\;\;\;\;\;(3)$$

So, did I make a mistake somewhere or is there a fault in the definition in my book? Please comment if my question is unclear =)

P.S. here you can find more details: [book](http://grapr.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/luenberger-linear-and-nonlinear-programming-3e-springer-2008.pdf), page 232

Comment: You divide two sides of an inequality by $\nabla f(x_k)d_k\alpha$. How certain are you that it is positive?

Comment: +1 @Kirill I'm not =) Thank you, that might be it :) Maybe I was expecting it to be made clear in the text :) As a matter of fact in the book it seems that the derivative of $\phi(\alpha)$ has a negative slope :) I will post a picture of this :)

Comment: I think that might be all there is to it, to be honest.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help =) @Kirill by the way, if you can post your comment as an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: (1) and (2) are not equivalent, as 
you forgot to include the condition $\phi(\alpha) \le \phi(0) + \epsilon \phi'(0)\alpha$....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimization algorithms try to find a minimum, and so they mostly look at descent directions.

Looking at a descent direction you would have $\phi'(0)<0$, so the sign of inequality changes when dividing by $\phi'(0)$.